# Array with different Key => Value pairs into a table PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have generated a "master" array which looks a little like this:

```
Array ( [userID] => 152 [email] => xxxxx@googlemail.com [name] => Jay jay go go [stream] => 616 ) 
Array ( [userID] => 133 [email] => damxxxxian@indigo.com [name] => Damian T [stream] => 616 ) 
Array ( [userID] => 154 [email] => julie@indigo.com [name] => Julie1000 E [stream] => 615 [PROGRAMME] => Designer ) 
Array ( [userID] => 153 [email] => jay@indigo.com [name] => James1000 G [stream] => 616 [PROGRAMME] => Apple Develpepr )
```

This is the output from a loop through a single array, so each of these 4 arrays are have keys 0 - 3.

My problem is that I want a table creating to hold all this data, with each row representing a user, but the array keys can be slightly different. For example, the first 2 users have no "programme" array key/value, but I want there to be a column saying "programme" but have it empty for users that dont have this in their array.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You need to either over-compensate your database to store additional columns that are not always used, or use NoSQL to provide a more flexible storage mechanism for storing users with widely ranging attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished by merging all of those arrays into a single array. Loop through every item in the array, gathering the keys (in_array might help there). Loop through your keys array to print out all the column headers in your table, then when your script needs to output the array you can simply run in a loop over each person, looping through each property as it maps to the column. That's kind of abstract, but I think you can fill in the rest. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I have just been looking and thinking something similar, by looping through after printing out the headers and saying "if this array key equals the header, then add the value" sort of thing? I'll have a go, thanks!

Comment: Let me know if you get stuck or need more specifics. I think you're going to have to have that initial loop where you pull out your keys though. I don't see a way around that.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a list of columns to include in the table, and then for each user, use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check whether there is a value for each column:

```
$columnNames = array('userID', 'email', 'name', 'stream', 'PROGRAMME');

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($columnNames as $columnName) {
        echo '<td>';
        if (isset($user[$columnName])) {
            echo htmlspecialchars($user[$columnName]);
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I didn't mistake your question, by doing this, you can create new array with max array keys;

```
$data = array(
    array('userID' => 152, 'email' => 'xxxxx@googlemail.com', 'name' => 'Jay jay go go', 'stream' => 616),
    array('userID' => 133, 'email' => 'damxxxxian@indigo.com', 'name' => 'Damian T', 'stream' => 616),
    array('userID' => 154, 'email' => 'julie@indigo.com', 'name' => 'Julie1000 E', 'stream' => 615, 'PROGRAMME' => 'Designer'),
    array('userID' => 153, 'email' => 'jay@indigo.com', 'name' => 'James1000 G', 'stream' => 616, 'PROGRAMME' => 'Apple Develpepr'),
);
$max_len = null;
$max_arr = null;
// First we find max array to grab its keys
foreach ($data as $i => $a) {
    $len = count($a);
    if ($max_len === null || $len > $max_len) {
        $max_len = $len;
        $max_arr = $data[$i];
    }
}
$max_arr_keys = array_keys($max_arr);
$data_new = array();
foreach ($data as $i => $a) {
    // and using max array keys here
    foreach ($max_arr_keys as $k) {
        // key exists? get value, or set as NULL
        $data_new[$i][$k] = isset($a[$k]) ? $a[$k] : null;
    }
}
print_r($data_new);
```

And output should look like this;

```
Array ( [userID] => 152 [email] => xxxxx@googlemail.com [name] => Jay jay go go [stream] => 616 [PROGRAMME] => null )
Array ( [userID] => 133 [email] => damxxxxian@indigo.com [name] => Damian T [stream] => 616 [PROGRAMME] => null ) 
Array ( [userID] => 154 [email] => julie@indigo.com [name] => Julie1000 E [stream] => 615 [PROGRAMME] => Designer ) 
Array ( [userID] => 153 [email] => jay@indigo.com [name] => James1000 G [stream] => 616 [PROGRAMME] => Apple Develpepr )
```